# Parsing 999 files with ediFabric

Tags: c#, edi, edifabric

I'm attempting to parse a valid 999 file with ediFabric using the 5010 Erata pack (the 837P parser works great by the way), but I'm having some difficulties. When I run the following code, I can't access any of the information from the file other than the ISA segment. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different way to process the 999 files?

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(FullFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var result = EdiFabric.Framework.Envelopes.X12.Interchange.LoadFrom(fs);
}
```

The result variable has the Isa property filled, but there are no groups. I can send a cleansed version of the file privately if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please send me the sample 999 file on private and I'll try to parse it. It's a very simple message so it shouldn't take long.
Alternatively you can enable logging and send me the log file as well. To log - add this to your config and point to a valid path:

```
<add key="EdiFabric.LogFile" value="C:\log.txt" />
```

btw, I'm one of the developers of ediFabric.